# Cross join of an unknown but defined N datasets at run time

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion

Is there a way to use SQL statement to partition datasets in a table and then cross join them? I have to currently do it in C# but it takes a long time for processing.

For illustration purpose, I have a Test table with the following items.

[image]

A1..A4, B1..B3, C1..C5 represent 3 partitions I am dealing with. Please note, the partitions are for illustration only. I do not know how many partitions are in the table unless I have to manually group them.

I would like to do a cross join on all 3 partitions (A,B,C) so that the final results should look like:

[image]

I know that recursion has to be used at some point but I am not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Thanks user1205746.  You mention that you don't know how many partitions you are are dealing with.  Does that mean that there could also be "D", "E","F" partitions that dynamically need to be included (for N additional columns), or that the number of records in "A", "B", "C" is unknown (but there will always just be three)?  Thanks

Comment: @alexgibbs: That is right. The partitions are unknown but defined at the time of running to statement, so it could not be hard coded. Sometimes it has up to 80 partitions

Comment: @alexgibbs: I just want to clarify my comment to answer your question more clearly. By partition, I meant there is possibility of having more columns D, E, F.. the number of partition could sometimes as many as 80+ partitions

Comment: Thanks user1205746 that helps to know.  As the number of columns increases, do their partition keys  by any chance remain alphabetical?  Do follow a regular pattern?  For example A,B,C,D...Y,Z,AA,AB...BA,BB...CA,CB?

Comment: @alexgibbs: Thank you for your questions. Actually, A, B, C, D... are just for illustration only. There is no pattern amongst the columns. The only tie is the group. A1, ..., An belong to group A, so on and so forth. In reality they are tied through a key... I am just trying to simplify and create a model for the issue. So, to answer your question the naming of the columns is random, A, Z, K, L... The only tie here is A1... An belong to A, Z1,...,, Zk belong to Z... I am thinking recursion should be applied somehow like ((A1...An) cross Join (B1,...,Bi))...cross join (Z1...Zh))..

Comment: Thanks user1205746, and apologies for multiple questions.  Returning variable numbers of columns can get kludgy (even in recent Oracle releases), esp given the column-names/partitions are unknown/variable.  However the actual generation of the cartesian product is straightforward.  I wondered whether it is acceptable in your case to return a set of comma(or whatever)-delimited strings (each representing one dynamic cross cross cross ... ), or whether it is a must that each value have its own column.  If the latter, is it acceptable if a fixed (lots, eg 100) of columns always return?

Comment: @alexgibbs: I see what you meant. I guess comma delimited string would work and I can easily convert it back to List<string>. The original issue is on my C# program and it took lot of time for processing the combinations (but long I meant days..). That is why I am thinking of using the database to do the weight lifting but got stuck at the possible use of recursion in sql statments. Thanks again for looking into this. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing can be done via a recursive query, though 80+ x-joins levels is a pretty unimaginable quantity of data.  I'll include an example below that generates a comma-separated set of strings, with each record representing one path through the cross-joins.

Given the nature of the example data, the example will use all leading alphabetical characters in each record as the record's partition (this would need to be adapted if the real data differs from the example pattern.)

First, create the test data:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE(ITEM VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY );

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('A1');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('A2');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('A3');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('A4');

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('B1');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('B2');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('B3');

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('C1');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('C2');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('C3');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('C4');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('C5');
COMMIT;
```

Then query.  At this point, 60 rows are expected, as there are 4 * 3 * 5 records across the 'A', 'B', 'C' groups.

Mechanically the below example will partition the records by they alphabetical prefix (In the provided data, into 'A', 'B', 'C' partitions).
Then, it will (arbitrarily) start with the (alphabetically) first partition ('A' in this case, though it is dynamically determined), and recursively connect each record in that partition to all records in the (alphabetically) next partition ('B' in this case), creating two-node paths and multiplying the number of records as it does so.

Then same process is then repeated for each two-node path into the next partition ('C' in this case) where the partitions are exhausted and it stops.  Then, only those paths that represent a full tree from root to leaf (three nodes in this example) are accepted.

```
WITH PARTITIONED_RECORD AS (
    SELECT ITEM,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(ITEM, '^[A-Z]{1,}') ASC) AS PARTITION_SORT,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ITEM ASC NULLS LAST) AS ABSOLUTE_SORT
    FROM TEST_TABLE),
     RAW_GRAPH AS (
         SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ITEM,',' ) AS CONNECTION_PATH,
                CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF AS LEAF_MARKER
                FROM PARTITIONED_RECORD
         START WITH PARTITION_SORT = 1
         CONNECT BY PARTITION_SORT = PRIOR PARTITION_SORT + 1
                AND ABSOLUTE_SORT > PRIOR ABSOLUTE_SORT)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(CONNECTION_PATH,'^,',NULL) AS CROSS_JOINED_SET
FROM RAW_GRAPH
WHERE LEAF_MARKER = 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Result:

```
CROSS_JOINED_SET
A1,B1,C1
A1,B1,C2
A1,B1,C3
A1,B1,C4
A1,B1,C5
A1,B2,C1
...
A4,B3,C3
A4,B3,C4
A4,B3,C5

60 rows selected.
```

Then test with additional partitions.  First, adding a single element to the new parititon.

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('D1');
```

And re-query (60 rows still expected, as there is no expansion in the x-join):

```
CROSS_JOINED_SET
...
A4,B3,C2,D1
A4,B3,C3,D1
A4,B3,C4,D1
A4,B3,C5,D1

60 rows selected.
```

And add a 2nd element to the 'D' partition, and re-query (120 records now expected):

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('D2');
```

Result:

```
CROSS_JOINED_SET
A1,B1,C1,D1
A1,B1,C1,D2
A1,B1,C2,D1
A1,B1,C2,D2
...
A4,B3,C4,D1
A4,B3,C4,D2
A4,B3,C5,D1
A4,B3,C5,D2

120 rows selected.
```

it
And a fifth group added with two records (240 rows expected):

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('EJY1017');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES ('EJY1018');
```

Result:

```
CROSS_JOINED_SET
A1,B1,C1,D1,EJY1017
A1,B1,C1,D1,EJY1018
A1,B1,C1,D2,EJY1017
A1,B1,C1,D2,EJY1018
...
A4,B3,C5,D1,EJY1017
A4,B3,C5,D1,EJY1018
A4,B3,C5,D2,EJY1017
A4,B3,C5,D2,EJY1018

240 rows selected.
```

**EDIT: Adding another variation on this, that uses dynamic cross joins.**

Another approach is to generate the x-joins in dynamic sql.  The below example again returns comma-separated strings, but does so via `CROSS JOIN` statements.

--Create return type (not really necessary)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE STRINGS IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/
```

-- And a function that detects the different groups and makes a cross-join for each.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION XJOIN RETURN STRINGS
    IS
    V_HEADER CHARACTER VARYING(512 BYTE) := ' SELECT ';
    V_XJOINS CHARACTER VARYING(32000 BYTE) := NULL;
    V_BUCKETS STRINGS := STRINGS();
    V_RESULTS STRINGS := STRINGS();
BEGIN

    SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR(ITEM,'^[A-Z]{1,}')
        BULK COLLECT INTO V_BUCKETS
    FROM TEST_TABLE ORDER BY 1 ASC;

    FOR BUCKET_INDEX IN 1..V_BUCKETS.COUNT
        LOOP
            IF BUCKET_INDEX > 1 THEN
                V_HEADER := V_HEADER||'||CHR(44)||';
                V_XJOINS := V_XJOINS||' CROSS JOIN ';
            END IF;
            V_HEADER := V_HEADER||V_BUCKETS(BUCKET_INDEX);
            V_XJOINS := V_XJOINS || UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE(Q'! (SELECT ITEM AS %s FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE ITEM LIKE '%s%') !',V_BUCKETS(BUCKET_INDEX),V_BUCKETS(BUCKET_INDEX));
        END LOOP;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (V_HEADER||' FROM '||V_XJOINS) BULK COLLECT INTO V_RESULTS;
    RETURN V_RESULTS;
END;
/
```

-- And call it:

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE ( XJOIN());
...
A2,B3,C5,D2,EJY1018
A3,B3,C5,D2,EJY1018
A4,B3,C5,D2,EJY1018
240 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks @user1205746 Ok, I've added one recursive approach here, that returns a single column of comma-separated strings.  I'm interested in feedback about the performance of this kind of approach against the real data (esp given the need to substring things into their partitions).  Please let me know how this fares when compared to extracting the data and performing the x-join subsequently.   There are other (non-recursive) approaches available that could possibly perform better.   Thanks

Comment: Thanks again for your assistance. The solution is very slick and eloquent. I'll give it a try as soon as my computer stops processing the C# program to address the same issue. It has been running since yesterday. Once I have the results, I will report back to you.. It may not be today, not sure how long it will take for my slow program to finish what it is doing. But I will sure give you feedback. Again, your time and assistance are really appreciated!!

Comment: I have the chance to test your suggestion. My actual "Test" table have 483 rows and only 12 columns and my Temp Table Space has already tapped out. I will ask our dba to increase the space to see it finishes. This is the error (not your error, just insufficient diskspace)

Comment: ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 12800 in tablespace TEMP
01652. 00000 -  "unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s"
*Cause:    Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for
           a temporary segment in the tablespace indicated.
*Action:   Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more
           files to the tablespace indicated.

Comment: I am curious about your solution without using recursion for comparison sake. If I submit an different request regarding the same problem asking for a solution without using recursion, would you catch it and reply?

Comment: Thanks @user1205746 for the follow-up.  The temp-space exceptions aren't surprising -- when the possibility dozens (80+) cross-joins came up, I wondered about the exponential expansion and the sheer volume of data that is possible in repeated x-join, and what could consume that much data.  Even with just 12 x-joins across 483 rows, that looks like ~2E19 rows. (22,563,490,300,366,186,081 
 assuming equal partitions of 41 rows each).  If each row is 20 bytes, that is crossing 10^20 bytes territory.  Perhaps the data will need to be processed in smaller sub-sets to keep within gigabyte scale?

Comment: As for the non-recursive approaches, I'd think that can just be added as an alternative here.  I probably won't have a chance today but will try to add another alternative on Monday.  Thanks

Comment: Totally agreed with your comment. That is what I plan to do next after I have asked our dba to increase the temp diskspace to 128 GB

Comment: Adding another solution here is fine. Alternatively, I have submitted another question. It is arguably a different approach for the similar topic since the later is the performance comparison between the 2 methods and not a different approach of the same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56080271/cross-join-of-an-unknown-but-defined-n-datasets-at-run-time-non-recursive-version. But it is up to you to decide where you would like to put your solution. Either way is equally appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @user1205746 I added another alternative here following my prior answer as an edit, that may have different performance to compare.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you for providing the non recursive version. I will try it and report back... Currently with the recursive version, I can only go up to 5 columns with 192 records. My temp space of 128 GB tapped out if it goes over to 6 columns. I would think while the non recursive version may be faster, since the numbers of combination is the same, it may require the same amount of temp space..anyway, will see... I'll let you know after I run it...

Comment: Follow up on your non recursive method. With the same data set of 5 columns, 192 records, when I use the non recursive method, I got this error:

Comment: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "AXIUM.XJOIN2", line 21
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           .

Comment: Looks like you have already set the string limit to the max already... I am going to do some digging when I have a few minutes to spare. At this point, looks like the recursive alternative is more clean cut and flexible. I just need to ask for more temp space and/or partition my dataset to more controllable parts or using the power of cloud computation.

Answer (score 0):

this is TSQL, but it might help you create something similar in ORACLE.

```
WITH DATA_temp as (
    SELECT 'A1' ID UNION 
    SELECT 'A2' ID UNION 
    SELECT 'B1' ID UNION 
    SELECT 'B2' ID UNION 
    SELECT 'D1' ID UNION 
    SELECT 'D2' ID UNION 
    SELECT 'c1' ID UNION 
    SELECT 'c2' ID  
    ) 


    SELECT ID, DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY LEFT(ID,1)) AS RN
    INTO #TEMP
    FROM DATA_temp;

DECLARE 
    @X varchar(2) = '1'
    ,@TB varchar(2)
    ,@SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)


WHILE @X <= (SELECT MAX(RN) FROM #TEMP)
BEGIN
SET @TB = (SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(ID,1) ID FROM #TEMP WHERE rn = @X)
SET @SQL = ISNULL(@SQL,'') + '(SELECT ID FROM #TEMP WHERE rn ='+ @X+' ) AS '+@TB+'  CROSS JOIN
'
SET @X = @X + 1
END 

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM '+ LEFT(@SQL,LEN(@SQL) - 13)

EXEC(@SQL)
```